A geometry question from BDMO 2024
$\triangle AFG$ is a triangle. $B$ and $C$ are two points on $AF$ and $AG$ such that $FB=BC=CG$.
The angle-bisectors of $\angle ABC$ and $\angle ACB$ intersect the sides $AG$ and $AF$ at points $E$ and $D$ respectively. Prove that $DE\parallel FG$. (BDMO 2024 junior P3)
My solution for this problem:
By some angle chasing and isosceles triangle, we get that, line $FC$ is parallel to $BE$, $BG$ is parallel to $DC$. By homothety we know that $\triangle ADC$ will go to $\triangle ABG$ and $\triangle ABE$ will go to $\triangle AFC$. It implies that line $DE$ goes to line $BC$. Then, we just construct another triangle $\triangle AB'C'$ such that $B'F=FG=GC'$. By similar arguments, we are done.
Is that right? If not, then please give me a solution.

From the [tag:solution-verification] tag wiki: "A question with this tag should include an explanation for why the argument presented is not convincing enough."

Oh sorry .I am a beginner so I just didn't know that stuff.

It's okay. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

You can make a simpler argument once you have your parallel lines: $\frac{AB}{AF}=\frac{AE}{AC}$, $\frac{AC}{AG}=\frac{AD}{AB}$ with cross-multiplication leads to $\frac{AE}{AG}=\frac{AD}{AF}$ so $DE \parallel FG$.

Your solution is wrong.
You're saying that $H(ED) = CB, H(CB) = GF$ to conclude that $ED \parallel CB \parallel GF$.
However, you made the incorrect assumption that the homothety factor is the same in both cases, which it need not be. What we actually have is  $H_1(FC) = BG$ (with scale factor $\frac{AC}{AG}$) and $H_2(BE) = CF$ (with scale factor $\frac{AB}{AF}$).
Another way to realize that $ED \not \parallel BC$, is that $ BC \not \parallel FG$ unless the triangle is isosceles (through side length chasing), which is what makes the scale factor the same.

RobinSparrow mentions in the comments how to complete the solution based on OP's observation that $BE \parallel FC, CD \parallel GB$ (which is all that we need) to conclude that $DE \parallel FG$.

Thank you to all for contributing .
